# Make all SwiperSlides to grow in height if one slide grows

Tags: css

I have a `Swiper` where `swiper` slides have different heights. I want to make them all the same height. I tried using `flexbox` and `align-items: stretch` but even then, as you can see in the attached image below, other cards are not growing to the height of the tallest card.

Here is the HTML for the Swiper:

```html
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" style="width: 244.667px;margin-right: 10px;">
      <div class="benefit-card">
        <img src='../../../images/benefits1.png' />
        <h5 class="benefit-title">
          Report card to parents
        </h5>
        <p class="benefit-card-description section-body-text">
          Get personalized weekly emails to evaluate your child's performance and progress
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" style="width: 244.667px;margin-right: 10px;">
      <div class="benefit-card">
        <img src='../../../images/benefits1.png' />
        <h5 class="benefit-title">
          Mentor support
        </h5>
        <p class="benefit-card-description section-body-text">
          2 mentor sessions in case of needing help by the kid
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
.swiper-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    transition-property: transform;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.swiper-slide {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.benefit-card {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 1.4rem;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
```

I am not sure why, even though the container has `display: flex` and `align-items: stretch`, the children are not all the same height. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]